# Definition for Mathematical Formula

Tags: terminology, definitions

Imagine that you were writing an elementary book, for example for high school learners, and at the beginning you had a glossary where you wanted to write the definitions for common mathematical words (e.g. numerical expression, algebraic expression, variable, equation, etc.) to help the reader make sense of those words when they appeared throughout the text. In this setting, what would you write to explain/define what a mathematical formula is?

Imagine that you wanted to put an entry for mathematical formula in a table like in these [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYLdJ.jpg), taken from the book Algebra and Trigonometry: Structure and Method, Book 2
which you can read [here](https://archive.org/details/algebratrigonome00brow/page/n31/mode/2up), if you have create an account.

I would like to avoid circular definitions.

---

**Some context**

The term formula seems to raise confusion with some frequency and  this can be seen by the number of Math Stackexchange questions that appeared over the years:

1. [what-is-the-difference-between-equation-and-formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38155/what-is-the-difference-between-equation-and-formula)
2. [what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-and-a-formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082718/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-and-a-formula)
3. [what-is-the-correct-meaning-of-term-formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4146122/what-is-the-correct-meaning-of-term-formula)
4. [in-the-context-of-mathematics-what-is-the-difference-between-equation-and-formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296654/in-the-context-of-mathematics-what-is-the-difference-between-equation-and-formu)
5. [what-is-the-difference-between-formula-and-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316470/what-is-the-difference-between-formula-and-function)
6. [difference-between-formula-and-algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330595/difference-between-formula-and-algorithm)

After some investigation it seems that people use the term mathematical formula to mean (mainly) two things:

1. Any mathematical sentence that uses symbols (e.g. equations, inequations/inequalities, identities). Which makes equations a kind of formula.
2. A rule for expressing a subject in terms of some other variables (as stated in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38155/what-is-the-difference-between-equation-and-formula/4254850?noredirect=1#comment9398749_4254850)). Or a procedure to compute some value of interest. Usually written as two expressions connected by an equals sign. Which makes formulas a kind of equation.

[Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Formula.html) seems to define a formula as the first. Many books use the term formula for the rules used to compute areas and volumes, and there is also the quadratic formula which provides the solution(s) to a quadratic equation. These are instances of the second definition.
Less frequently, I've also seen people call formula to any string of mathematical symbols, making an expression a kind of formula. Another example is the book [Introduction to Algebra](https://books.google.com/books?id=1CwTDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA23&redir_esc=y) that defines formula as a synonym for expression in page 23 ([according to this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809529/is-32-5-a-equation?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment3697812_1809529)).

---

**EDIT**
After reading some of the comments I feel the need reword the first part of my original question to:

> Imagine that you were writing a book that revisits elementary
> mathematics subjects/areas but from an advanced standpoint, for
> example for advanced high school learners or people preparing to an
> undergraduate mathematics heavy course. One example of such book might
> be Serge Lang's Basic Mathematics.
>
> Now consider that in the beginning of this book you had a glossary
> where you wanted to write the definitions for common mathematical
> words (e.g. numerical expression, algebraic expression, variable,
> equation, etc.) to help the reader make sense of those words when they
> appeared throughout the text.
>
> In this setting, what would you write to **explain/define what a
> mathematical formula is?**

I personally think that the answers given up to the point in time of this edit fit both the original question and this reword, but would prefer if new answers take this revision into consideration.

**EDIT 2**
I accepted @ryang's answer because it has all the information requested by the Question, but also found [Charles Wells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Wells_(mathematician))' work, which helped me interiorize stuff:

- [Website](https://abstractmath.org/)
- [A report on mathematical discourse](https://abstractmath.org/Handbook/handbook.pdf), which has an entry for 'formula'.

Comment: To me, the 2nd definition you give feels like it's headed in more of the right direction. I'll be interested to see what others think.

Comment: (1 of 2)  I doubt the importance of a precise definition for this particular term.  I'm thinking about my own high school math experience and I don't remember the different usages of that term (as you've shown) ever troubling me.  Didn't help me crunch the quadratic equation.  Or help me figure out what subtracting a negative number means.

Comment: (2 of 2)  By the way, "high school math" is awfully imprecise.  What subject, grade, track does your book cover?  P.s.  See Feynman's criticism of new math definition obsessions:  https://fs.blog/richard-feynman-teaching-math-kids/  In all seriousness, I would write the book, then the glossary, then check your own usage.  Not play Bourbaki with definitions-first approach.  (But I'm not too worried about the impact on kids.  Very few book projects like this get finished, and if finished sold/implemented.)

Comment: I agree with “guest”’s comments. This question is not something that troubles students in a practical sense. An example of something that is important that troubles students is correctly rearranging equations, for example in order to make a variable the subject of a formula/equation. If one of my students where to ask me what a formula is, then $(2)$ would be my default answer: it’s an equation with $y=f(x)$ or $u=f(t),$ etc.

Comment: With all due respect, it does bother me, or I wouldn't be asking it. And it seems to bother other people, as many have asked before. I understand your point and it is true that it can be considered a pedantic question. However, your comments are not really adding anything to the table, as I am a student with a doubt and after reading your comments the doubt persists.

Comment: I can think of one (famous) formula that is *not* an equality : Sterling's formula: $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$. About the "It does not trouble students" outlook. I think expecting students to be bothered or otherwise by such is one thing.  And for the teacher to get their "glossary" — I prefer to say ontology — right is quite another

Comment: @Rusi Good example about Stirling; that tilde means "is asymptotic to (i.e., has essentially the same behaviour for large $n$ as)", which I guess is kinda an equality (it definitely isn't an *in*equality). $\quad$ Re: your 2nd point: for sure; that previous comment was somewhat strange considering the nature of this SE subsite.

Comment: Well dunno abt "not an inequality" @ryang — given the lhs is an integer and rhs is transcendental . You could equally(!!) say it's *always* an inequality except when $n \rightarrow \infty$. Of course this is semantics; bottom line is "approximates" is significant

Comment: @Rusi Haha, touché! (But of course what is of interest is the *same*ness of the LHS and RHS as the index blows up.)

Comment: Just for fun I tried out a python script which compares (i, i!, the sterling approx) for [0,10)
`[(0, 1, 0.0), (1, 1, 0.9221370088957891), (2, 2, 1.9190043514889832), (3, 6, 5.836209591345864), (4, 24, 23.506175132893294), (5, 120, 118.0191679575901), (6, 720, 710.078184642185), (7, 5040, 4980.395831612462), (8, 40320, 39902.39545265671), (9, 362880, 359536.87284194835)]`

Comment: Regarding the edit, I don't think I shifted the goalpost. I just felt the need to reword it because some people seem to feel that regular high school students don't care about terminology. In reality the level of scholarity of the student that the book would be for is not the important part. I'm just using it to give the idea that I want the explain the definition of formula to someone who has enough background to understand term definitions and notices the lack of a clear one in most bibligraphies. The goal is the same and your original answer still fits in my view.

Comment: indeed it does  

Comment: If you check this [entry in his blog](https://abstractmath.org/MM/MMCognitiveDissonance.htm) you will notice that he acknowledges that people might experience mental dissonance, an expression (no pun intended) you used, when dealing with how people use the word 'formula'. So I don't feel like my questions are that farfetched.

Comment: Yes. Your EDIT 2 makes it sound like his take (on p. 101) complements what I wrote, when it fact it reiterates, affirms and cements the explanations that I supplied, elaborated on and repeated throughout the thread below. In any case, I can understand how two different authors arriving at the same conclusions, with pretty much the same phrasings, is finally persuasive to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In formal logic, ‘formula’ has a standard and precise definition. Roughly speaking, take a constant and/or variable, apply a non-logical operation (e.g., addition) if desired, repeat if desired, this gives a ‘term’ (notice the deviation from its common meaning in mathematics); relate two terms using the equality relation to obtain an ‘atomic formula’; apply a logical operation or quantifier to atomic formulae finitely many (including zero) times to obtain **formulae**; a formula is then called a sentence/proposition precisely when it has no free variable.

But formal logic is tangential to your question.

> 1. Any mathematical sentence that uses symbols (e.g., equations, inequations/inequalities, identities).
>
>    Which makes equations a kind of formula.

What's missing from this characterisation is some mention that a formula expresses a rule or required relationship or somesuch.

After all, the equation $3x^2+7x=8$ is typically decidedly not a formula.

> 2. as stated in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38155/what-is-the-difference-between-equation-and-formula/4254850?noredirect=1#comment9398749_4254850):
>
>    > Perhaps: A **formula** is a rule for expressing a subject in terms of some other variable(s); for example, $V=πr^2h$ expresses a cylinder's volume in terms of its radius and height.
>
>    Which makes formulas a kind of equation.

The keyword here is *rule*, which is rather more specific than “equation”, and switching it out alters the meaning.

And certainly, $V=πr^2h$ is not an identity, as triples like $(1,1,1)$ do not satisfy it. The example says that for each *cylinder* with volume, radius and height $V,r,h,$ respectively, the attributes obey the relationship $V=πr^2h.$

---

**Addendum**

> Would you say that there exist  formulas that contain an inequality symbol?

I'd typically call such an object an ‘inequality constraint’ rather than a ‘formula’.

In the language of first-order arithmetic on the other hand, $x<y$ is an ‘open formula’ [side note: it can be rewritten as $\exists r\: (x'+r=y)].$

Maybe don't try to conflate the formal-logic and informal usages of ‘formula’.

> For example, in Spivak's Calculus, 4th Edition, page 33 he writes: "When does equality hold in the formula $G_n \le A_n$?"

It is apparent from the context that Spivak is using the term 'formula’ in the formal-logic sense. (But since this is an Analysis, not Logic, text, I’d probably rewrite the question as “When does equality hold in the sentence/statement/assertion $G_n \le A_n$?”)

There's similarly no ambiguity in my various usages (in the third line and the previous sentence) of ‘term’: (1) in formal logic, $7y+8$ is a term (2) in mathematics, the expression $7y+8$ is not a term (3) the word ‘term' is a term.

In mathematics, the word ‘formula’ is not part of the theory, so does not have a rigorous (or at least widespread rigorously consistent/matching) definition. Possibly, Spivak's text contains a definition of ‘formula’ in the preface or glossary, and the quoted usage above goes with it?

At the end of the day, don't forget about the context; I mean, have you ever found the word ‘formula’ ambiguous in spite of its surrounding context?

Comment: Would you say that there exist relationships that are rules but are represented by inequalities instead of equalities? In other words, are there any formulas that contain an inequality symbol?

Comment: For example, in Spivak's Calculus, 4th Edition, page 33 he writes: "When does equality hold in the formula $G_n \leq A_n$? "
(Edited because the inequality sign was wrong)

Comment: Consider the triangle inequality: If $x$, $y$, and $z$ are the lengths of the sides of the triangle, with no side being greater than $z$, then the triangle inequality states that $z \leq x + y$. This reads to me as a rule or a relationship between a variable in terms of other variables. It is obviously not a way to compute $z$, but it is a type of law that $z$ respects. Would you call it a formula?

Comment: Analysis I, by Terence Tao, also uses the word formula frequently. He seems to use it for definitions, for example on page 79  of the 3rd edition: We now define the operation of subtraction $x − y$ of two integers by the formula $x − y := x + (−y)$.

Comment: As my answers to your previous two comments are all in the above addendum, I don't wish to have a protracted chat reiterating the same. $\quad$ But to elaborate: (1) when writing mathematics and one wishes to use formal-logic terminology calling $z \leq x + y$ a 'formula', then to be consistent, shouldn't one also call $7y+8$ a 'term'?  (2) I would call the triangle inequality a 'formulation' rather than a 'formula', but— *insert here the final paragraph of the addendum* —I wouldn't find it jarring if an author calls it a 'formula'.

Comment: Please understand that because the terminology under discussion is not within some theory (since we aren't discussing formal logic), your question belongs just as much to English-language SE as it does to mathematics SE. While the ontology is important, so is context!

Comment: Well I think I agree with the "rule for expressing a subject in terms of some other variables", and that holds for the most part in elementary books. It is when I go to more advanced books that it confuses me. That is the reason why I was asking if there where cases where the word could be used but don't quite respect the "equality relationship". Because in the hypothetical book of the original question, I would like to have a column, next to the definition, with different examples of formulas that appear in the wild but not necessarily use the common and basic ones like areas and volumes.

Comment: Yep. Remember that when you initially misquoted me when creating this post, I'd privately pointed out that the word "equation" does not appear in my proposed explanation / informal definition? My elaboration (in the form of the above Answer) still doesn't make such assertions, and I'm careful to use words like "typically". Have you seen anyone call the triangle inequality a formula? (No.) Is it invalid to call the triangle inequality a formula? (No, because no axiom, law, widespread standard, or *definition*, for that matter, is really being violated either.) I made several references

Comment: to formal logic; those aren't merely tangential to the discussion, as they shed light on why folks might call $x−y=x+(−y)$ a 'formula', specifically, an open formula. As such (I'm repeating myself), $x−y$ is called a 'term'. Understandably though, without some clarifying preface/glossary, some readers might get confused and think, "$x$ is a term and $y$ is a term, but how is $x−y$ a term?"

Comment: I guess that you are right, people seem to use both formal logic definition and the "rule/law" definition, but don't feel the need to differentiate between the two.

Comment: Do not be mistaken though: your proposed Option 1 (borrowed from MathWorld) is not—and is not meaning to be—the formal-logic definition of 'formula', which I don't think is common anyway.

Comment: Isn't it an atomic formula?

Comment: No, that [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Formula.html)'s main explanation of 'formula' (which you adopted as Option 1) is just a careless (alternatively: highly informal) phrasing of Option 2. Indeed, after presenting that explanation, it goes on to elaborate that this is different from 'formula''s meaning in formal logic.

Comment: At this point I'm confused enough to feel like I should open a question in some Exchange site asking for two listings: one of examples of mathematical formulas and another of "not mathematical formulas", starting with the ones we encounter in middle school and ending with the ones we find in Analysis. 

Comment: Your confusion stems from falsely attributing rigour to an informal explanation (MathWorld's), and then falsely attributing formality to Spivak & Tao's informal usages of the word (which has no problem because there is no ambiguity, even as there may be slight inconsistency if they selectively call $x−y=x+(−y)$ a formula without calling $x-y$ a term). I did point out from the outset that the formal-logic perspective is tangential to your Question, and subsequently reminded not to conflate the two perspectives.

Comment: Side note: formal logic is generally a bad place to seek definitions for mathematics, and is itself even riddled with conflicting terminology and notation.

Comment: " *when I go to more advanced books, it confuses me. are there cases where the word 'formula' could be used but don't quite respect the equality relationship?* " Consider the fact that every inequality can be rephrased/reframed as an equality (example in my Addendum paragraph 1). How's that now?

Comment: So, when mathematicians are writing for example an Analysis book, they might use the word "formula" in the formal logic sense even though they are using it in a non rigorous way (because mathematics is written in an informal way). When I see "formula" in the text I can (sometimes) replace it with "an equality that holds in that universe". For example, paraphrasing Spivak's Calculus page 77: "You can easily check the formula $a \cdot (b \cdot v) = (ab) \cdot v$", I can interpret it as "the (logical) formula $\forall a, b, v, \quad a \cdot (b \cdot v) = (ab) \cdot v$ can be shown to be true" ?

Comment: 1. "*because mathematics is written in an informal way*" Bingo! $\quad$ 2. "*When I see "formula" in the text I can...*" Why keep over-complicating it? There are many contronyms in the English language: 'clip' means attach or detach depending on the context; do you despair or experience mental dissonance at the sentence, "she clipped my hair"? $\quad$ 3. "*For example, paraphrasing...*" This is a separate issue (let's not keep extending the topic) and is called [implicit universal quantification](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4347899/21813).

Comment: The issue with your argument is that 'clip' has two well defined meanings and I can select the correct one depending on the context. The word 'formula' has a well defined meaning in formal logic but a not so well defined one in mathematics. So I asked for the mathematics definition in the original question. However, since it not a "written in stone" definition, and since we reached to the conclusion that people seem to use both in a single text, I asked if I was correctly parsing the last Spivak example as an instance of the case where the formal logic meaning was being used.

Comment: Also, I know what implicit universal quantification is, I was simply asking if he was calling a formula to that instance of it.


It is true that we shouldn't keep this conversation here. Are you willing/available to continue in a chat? Because I can't/shouldn't post another Question If I'm not sure what my doubt is. I upvoted your answer btw.

Comment: 1. "*since we reached the conclusion that people seem to use both in a single text*" No: I never concluded that Tao was using conflicting definitions within the same usage (or even the same text), and explicitly indicated that the formal-logic definition is UNcommon.  $\quad$
2. "*since it not a "written in stone" definition*" MANY terms in formal logic (but also in mathematics), have conflicting definitions across texts! The practice of mathematics is an art. Get used to it.

Comment: So for you $a \cdot (b \cdot v) = (ab) \cdot v$  is a rule for expressing a subject: $a \cdot (b \cdot v)$; in terms of some other variable(s): $(ab) \cdot v$?

Comment: 3. " *The word 'formula' has no well defined one in mathematics.*" The definition that I suggested is as well-defined as most definitions in the Oxford dictionary. $\quad$ 4. Repeating myself: your false attribution of rigour and formality where none was intended is the root of your confusion re: all this. And while etymology provides clues to meaning, it does not *dictate* the framing of current usage; plainly speaking: just because a definition has a biblical (formal-logic) root does not mean that we are writing the bible (or discussing formal logic) when drawing on that particular defn!

Comment: And you are wrong to think that a good dictionary contains every single usage definition of a word; it is in fact not uncommon to find that no definition (out of the listed 29) has adequately captured a particular usage nuance. [Comment #6](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/definition-for-mathematical-formula/25352?noredirect=1#comment64750_25352) might be pertinent.

Comment: Please don't be mad at me. I genuinely want this to make sense. Can you answer my previous question?

Comment: Formula: a rule for expressing a subject in terms of some other variable(s).
Is [$a \cdot (b \cdot v)$] the subject and [$(ab) \cdot v$] the way it is being expressed in terms of other variables? Do you read it this way?

Comment: So he is using the formal logic definition of formula there. But when he calls $arcsin'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x ^2}}$ a formula, he is using the "a rule for expressing a subject in terms of some other variable(s)" definition. Is this true?

Comment: Just posted a new [comment](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/importance-of-standardization-of-definitions-of-mathematical-terms/25361#comment64838_25357) that is orthogonal to this thread.